# JPA manually create the @JoinTable

Tags: java, jpa, indexing, join

Hi I got a problem with JPA being slow. Using jps to map a model of queues, snapshots of queues and events.
Here are my Entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cmEvent")
public class Event implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3252213465022678048L;
  @Id
  @Column(name = "eventId")
  private long eventId;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
    name = "cmEventSnap",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "eventId"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "snapshotId"))
  private List<Snapshot> snapshots = new ArrayList<Snapshot>();
  // setters & getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cmSnapshot")
public class Snapshot implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3892306246413539227L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "snapshotId")
  private long snapshotId;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "snapshots", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
  // setters & getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cmQueue")
public class Queue implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2209454705341173802L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "queueId")
  private long queueId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "queue", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Snapshot> snapshots = new ArrayList<Snapshot>();
  // setters & getters
}
```

So my problem comes to the fact that the JoinTable for the Events Entity automatically created from JPA is getting quite big and it's getting slow as the time passes.

I though of creating indexes for that table on the column eventsId.

Is there a way to do it by using the annotation?
If not, how can I manually create the jointable with a new Entity?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate, Toplink, ...?

Comment: @ŁukaszRżanek I am using jpa for now but can add Hibernate.

Comment: `@Index` in won't work neither in plain JPA, nor Hibernate. You can manually add index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time You can't really do anything about that with Java annotations. And it's a well known pitfall of using JPA's many-to-many with, i.e. [Hibernate](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4263).

Teneo (Eclipse EMF) is an implementation which can do that for you (create the necessary indexes).

So, for now, you're stuck with manual index creation issuing DDL query on your RDBMS...

Otherwise [here you will find an example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) (with additional features, but general idea is the same) of how to create a join table manually.

Comment: Right so after reading the bug report, my proposed solution to manually create an Entity to hold the data for those two entities would be good?

Comment: Could you point me out how to do that? I suppose the two Entities (Event and Snapshot) would hold new variables for EventSnapJoin `@OneToMany`, yeah ?

Comment: If you need pure Java solution (no manual DDLs) then yes, you can create an entity and map it values `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` respectively. Then `@Index` will work just fine. Still it won't be perfect and you must keep in mind lazy and eager initialization of such connection. Overall - pain in the bottom...

Answer (score 2):

Creating indexes from JPA is not possible (though UniqueConstraints are supported). You should add the index manually via  your DBMS.

You could do it e.g. with Hibernate and `@Index` and then regenerate the model as soon as [this bug in Hibernate](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4263) is fixed. (I just leave the note on @Index to show that this actually exists)

Comment: No, one can not use `@Index` in this case - it's a known problem in Hibernate! Take a look [here](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4263)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not all JPA implementations have such a problem creating indices on join tables, though obviously there's no JPA standard way. DataNucleus JPA certainly handles it (since the core code is used by JDO too and that standard *does* allow indices there).